# To "null" or not to "null" my class's attributes

Tags: java

When I write a class in Java, I like to initialize the attributes which are set to a default value directly and attributes which are set by the caller in the constructor, something like this:

```
public class Stack<E> {
    private List<E> list;
    private int size = 0;

    public Stack(int initialCapacity) {
        list = new ArrayList<E>(initialCapacity);
    }

    // remainder omitted
}
```

Now suppose I have a Tree class:

```
public class Tree<E> {
    private Node<E> root = null;

    // no constructor needed, remainder omitted
}
```

Shall I set the root attribute to null, to mark that it is set to null by default, or omit the null value?

**EDIT:**

I came up with that idea after reading the sources of [LinkedList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html) and [ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html), which both clearly set their attributes (size in LinkedList and firstIndex/lastIndex in ArrayList) to 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no *need* to explicitly initialize a reference-typed attribute to `null`.  It will be initialized to null by default.  Similarly, there are default initialization rules for the primitive types:

- boolean attributes are initialized to `false`, and
- integral (including `char`), `float` and `double` attributes are all initialized to zero.

So the initialization of `size` in the example is also strictly unnecessary.

It is therefore purely a matter of style as to whether you do or do not initialize them.  My personal opinion is that it does not improve readability, and therefore is a waste of time.  (I don't write my code to be maintained by people who don't understand the basics of Java ...)

Comment: @Helper Method: You haven't given `size` a type, but I'm assuming it's an `int`. If so, it's the same situation -- it will be initialized to `0` automatically. If you have a team using a diverse set of languages with differing rules around this, perhaps the explicitness is useful, but at a technical level it is not needed.

Comment: @T.J. Re: your team using multiple languages - in that case, the boss should send everyone who needs it on a Java training course.  People who try to maintain programs in a language they are not familiar with are ... dangerous.

Comment: Well put: "I don't write my code to be maintained by people who don't understand the basics of Java". Knowing that fields are initialised to null/false/zero is indeed part of Java basics.

Comment: Has nothing to do with "basics of Java" and everything to do with "signalling intent".  If I just have a raw member declaration I'm signalling (in my code, at any rate) that the member is initialized elsewhere upon object creation (constructor, initializer) with a non-default value.  If I set a member's value in the declaration I'm signalling that this member is not guaranteed to be initialized elsewhere upon object creation.

Comment: @Jonik: Yes, knowing that they get initialised to the default value is part of Java basics, but knowing that *this* particular class actually means to use that default value is not.

Comment: @JUST - you might be signalling that, but other people don't follow this convention and won't pick up your signal.  Besides, it is not the sort of thing that they *should* rely on.  After all, how are they to know that you have followed your convention *consistently*.  What I'm saying is that it won't help *other people* read your code.

Comment: @Stephen C: Coding conventions are documented for a reason.  I assume that people entering a project have the courtesy to actually read relevant documentation to find their way around.  As to following consistently, that's what things like code reviews (even when spelled "pair coding") are for.

Comment: @JUST - Ah ... you are talking about a team convention, rather than a personal convention.  I guess if you have clearly documented that convention, and your team buys into it, that's OK.

Comment: @Arkku - the "intention" of the developer is largely irrelevant.  What matters is what the code actually does.  (If you have to reverse engineer the developer's intention in order to fix some bug, the code probably needs to be rewritten!)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are relying on these variables having the default value (0, `null`) for a new instance, I would initialise them to illustrate to the reader that this is the case. Otherwise they might have to read further to know there is no constructor where the variables are initialised (possibly to another value).

Edit: Of course, you are not required to initialise; I assume the question is about preferred style and this is my preference.

Answer (score 3):

It's a personal preference but IMHO it is better to omit it. References are initialized with null by default so you're only cluttering the code. The less code the better.